# How do I remove a Minecraft profile from the launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Minecraft Launcher 1.3.9 has buttons to create and edit profiles but not to remove one. How can I delete an individual profile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in the "Profile Editor" tab of the launcher. Just right click on the profile you want to delete, and hit "Delete Profile."

[image: Screenshot of the Profile Editor tab]

Comment: @TravisChristian Yeah, no kidding.

Answer (score -3):

The FTB launcher (gives mod packs)  let's you press the edit profile button and press the profile and press delete

Comment: I suppose by FTB you mean Feed The Beast?